# Does Dark Souls II SotFS have the patches built-in?

Tags: dark-souls-2-sotfs

I don't understand if DS2 SOTFS for PS4 comes with the patches or not, especially the fix for weapons breaking because the game ran at 60fps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Scholar of the First Sin is just an enhanced rerelease of Dark Souls II. From [this article](https://www.vg247.com/2014/11/25/dark-souls-2-scholar-of-the-first-sin-v-1-10-differences/), it looks like the base version of SotFS is what was version 1.10 in the original version of Dark Souls II.

> Finally, just to make things really confusing, **there will also be a re-release for PC (DirectX9), PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360, which is exactly the same as the 1.10 version but comes bundled with the DLC.**

---

The bug you are describing was fixed as of version 1.11, as mentioned in the [patch notes](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/game-patches#toc1). Credit to @pushasha for finding them.

> Fixed issue whereby weapon durability was decreased drastically when used on enemy corpses, friendly characters, etc. (Especially apparent for users running the game at 60 fps as the durability decrease rate was linked to the frame rate).

Thus, the base version of Scholar of the First Sin will need to be updated in order for this fix to be implemented.

Comment: I might be misreading this, but it looks like [the durability bug was fixed in v1.11](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/game-patches#toc1).

Comment: @pushasha yeah, that looks like the correct fix. I'll add this to the answer, thanks!